# jQuery logger plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, plugins

I'm working on a jQuery plugin that allows you to log any javascript class or object.
The idea is to override each function inside the object, or prototype of a function.

```
(function($)
{
    "use strict";

    $.log = function(object, logger)
    {
        if (!$.isFunction(logger))
        {
            logger = function(name, args)
            {
                console.log(name + "(" + $.makeArray(args).join(", ") + ")");
            };
        }

        var s = $.isFunction(object) ? object.prototype : object;

        for (name in s)
        {
            var fn = s[name];

            if ($.isFunction(fn))
            {
                s[name] = (function(name, fn)
                {
                    return function()
                    {
                        logger(name, arguments);
                        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
                    };
                })(name, fn);
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This seems to work for logging individual plugins. For example `$.log($.ui.tabs);` logs all the function calls inside the tabs prototype.

But when I want to log all of jQuery `$.log($);` it's giving me some reference error.
I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I'm under the impression it has something to do with either `this` or the arguments being passed, but I'm not sure.

Edit: Now I think about It some more it might also be caused because the overridden function always returns.

I created a fiddle to demo the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj6xN/4/

**EDIT:**

This is the code i ended up with, so far working perfectly:

```
(function($)
{
    "use strict";

    var Logger = function(options)
    {
        this.options = $.extend(this.defaults, options);
    };

    Logger.prototype = {
        defaults:
        {
            inherited: false,
            deep: false,
            logWriter: function(name, args)
            {
                console.log("CALL: " + name + "(" + $.makeArray(args).join(", ") + ")");
            }
        },
        augment: function(object)
        {
            var self = this;

            // Make sure this object is not already augmented
            if (object.__isAugmented__)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Set 'isAugmented' to prevent recursion
            object.__isAugmented__ = true;

            // Loop through the object
            for (var name in object)
            {
                var originalFunction = object[name];

                // If it's a function and the function is not inherited or 'inherited' is enabled augment it
                if ($.isFunction(originalFunction) && (object.hasOwnProperty(name) || self.options.inherited))
                {
                    // Wrap in self executing function so references to 'name' and 'orginalFunction' are maintained
                    object[name] = (function(name, originalFunction)
                    {
                        // If the function has a prototype and 'deep' is enabled augment that as well
                        if (self.options.deep && originalFunction.prototype)
                        {
                            self.augment(originalFunction.prototype);
                        }

                        var augmentedFunction = function()
                        {
                            // Execute log writer
                            self.options.logWriter(name, arguments);

                            // Call original function
                            return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
                        };

                        // Inherit prototype of original function
                        augmentedFunction.prototype = originalFunction.prototype;

                        // Return the augmented function
                        return augmentedFunction;
                    })(name, originalFunction);
                }
                // If it's a plain object and 'deep' is enabled augment that as well
                else if (self.options.deep && $.isPlainObject(originalFunction))
                {
                    self.augment(originalFunction);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $.log = function(object, options)
    {
        var logger = new Logger(options);

        // If the object is a function use it's prototype, otherwise assume a plain object
        object = $.isFunction(object) ? object.prototype : object;

        // Augment
        logger.augment(object);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Can be used like this:

```
$.log(<object or function> [,
{
    inherited: <bool>,
    deep: <bool>,
    logWriter: <function(name, args)>
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well look closely to the error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

Means you haven't defined name and since you are in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), you can't use a variable without defining it(normally if you do it, it'll be a global variable, but not in strict mode). So if you write a `var name` before it you won't get this error anymore.

Though there is another error for not having tab method. The other error says `tabs` is not a method of the object which is because when you wrap the function, you didn't inherit the prototype, so when the function is called with new, it doesn't have prototype functions(`tabs` is one of them).

Here's the fixed code : http://jsfiddle.net/Sj6xN/8/

Comment: The undeclared `name` variable is pretty obvious, i'm not getting that error though, `name` is a property of `window` so it's declared. How did you get that error? Totally forgot about the prototype inheritance though, thanks! I can't vote your answer up because i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You can "accept" my answer, you don't need reputation for that. The `name` would be property of window, if you have defined it out of this scope which is not a good thing and you should not use it here, or you're js interpreter doesn't support "strict mode" completely.

Comment: I tested the name variabele on the startpage of firefox and it was still declared. Don't see a "accept" button anywhere, marked it as usefull though.

Comment: Yeah, [name is a property of window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.name). It doesn't throw in firefox, but it throws in chrome. Not sure why. The accept button is right under the vote up, the empty tick.